# Stop scrolling RichTextBlock when manipulation start

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp

I have a chat that contains in RichTextBlock

```
<ScrollViewer Name="ChatScroll"
                              Margin="3"
                              ManipulationMode="All">
                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <helpers:ScrollHelper />
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <RichTextBlock>
                        <Paragraph>
                            <InlineUIContainer>
                                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedMedia.ChatMessages}"
                                      Margin="0">
                                    //SOME ELSE CODE
                                </ItemsControl>
                            </InlineUIContainer>
                        </Paragraph>
                    </RichTextBlock>
                </ScrollViewer>
```

So i need to scroll in bottom when get new message, BUT if I want to see the chat history I don’t need to scroll down.

My idea is to subscribe to the event ManipulationDelta and cancel the scroll down

```
public class ScrollHelper : Behavior<ScrollViewer>
{
    private double height = 0.0d;
    private ScrollViewer scrollViewer = null;
    private bool IsBusy = false;

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        //IsBusy = false;
        this.scrollViewer = this.AssociatedObject;
        this.scrollViewer.LayoutUpdated += ScrollViewer_LayoutUpdated;
        this.scrollViewer.ManipulationDelta += ScrollViewer_ManipulationDelta;
    }


    private void ScrollViewer_ManipulationDelta(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var verticalOffset = scrollViewer.VerticalOffset;
        var maxVerticalOffset = scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight; //sv.ExtentHeight - sv.ViewportHeight;

        if (maxVerticalOffset < 0 ||
            verticalOffset == maxVerticalOffset)
        {
            IsBusy = false;
        }
        else if (e.Delta.Translation.Y < 0 || e.Delta.Translation.Y > 0)
        {
            IsBusy = true;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();

        if (this.scrollViewer != null)
        {
            this.scrollViewer.LayoutUpdated -= ScrollViewer_LayoutUpdated;
        }
    }
    private void ScrollViewer_LayoutUpdated(object sender, object e)
    {
        if (!IsBusy)
        {
            if (Math.Abs(this.scrollViewer.ExtentHeight - height) > 1)
            {
                scrollViewer.ChangeView(0, scrollViewer.ExtentHeight, 1);
                this.height = this.scrollViewer.ExtentHeight;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But if I scroll the mouse wheel then the event does not work?  Is there an idea how to subscribe to the scroll wheel event? Or other ideas how not to send the scroll down while viewing the story

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an idea how to subscribe to the scroll wheel event?

Mouse wheel event will be handled internally by the scroller, so we could not subscribe this event directly, in general, we could subscribe [`ViewChanging`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.viewchanging) event that contain [`FinalView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewerviewchangingeventargs.finalview) and [`NextView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewerviewchangingeventargs.nextview) and we could compare the  `VerticalOffset` of `FinalView` and `NextView` to judge scroll down or up.